# Http GET : Possibly unhandled rejection

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

I am new with angular.
I want to get the data from an action name (MVC) using http.

In the console I got a GET line, then the following error occurs : 
"Possibly unhandled rejection:  ": {"data":"\r\n\r\n    \r\n "

My code in the html view file :

```
       [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult OPCVMLoad()
    {
        OPCVM opcvm1 = new OPCVM();
        opcvm1.OPCVMcode = 1;
        opcvm1.OPCVMname = "Bernardin";
        return Json(opcvm1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }



<script>

    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
    myApp.controller('OPCVMViewModel', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.OPCVM = {
            "OPCVMcode": "",
            "OPCVMname": ""
        };
        $scope.OPCVMs = {};

        $scope.TestClick = function TestClick() {
            alert("test clic");
        };

        $scope.GetAllData = function GetAllData() {
            alert("break point in function GetAllData");
            $http.get("GrilleFast/OPCVMLoad")
                .then(function (response)
                {
                    $scope.OPCVM  = response.data; 
                }) 

        };

    }]);

</script>


<div ng-controller="OPCVMViewModel">
    <input name="BtnAddNew" type="button" value="Load all OPCVM" ng-click="GetAllData()"  />
    {{OPCVM.OPCVMcode}}        <br />
    {{OPCVM.OPCVMname}}




</div>
```

My code in the .cs file (action MVC)

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult OPCVMLoad()
    {
        OPCVM opcvm1 = new OPCVM();
        opcvm1.OPCVMcode = 1;
        opcvm1.OPCVMname = "Bernardin";
        return Json(opcvm1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: I think you forgot some code :)

Comment: Please use `angularjs` for questions about AngularJS. `angular` is reserved for Angular version 2+

Answer (score 2):

It's just a warning telling you that an error occured into the Rest call, and you did not handle it.

You have 2 way to remove that "warning" :

1. you deal with every error :

---

```
        $http.get("GrilleFast/OPCVMLoad")
            .then(function (response)
            {
                $scope.OPCVM  = response.data; 
            }, function(error){
                 console.log(error); //
            }) ;
```

---

2. if you don't want to handle every possible error, you can disable it globally :

---

```
angular.module('myApp').config(['$qProvider', function($qProvider){
   $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);

}]);
```

I think it has been introduced with angular 1.5.9, you can find documentation about it here : [$qProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$qProvider)

Comment: thank you. I proceeded to the changes and now I have this message in the console  :
Object { data: "<!DOCTYPE html> <html>     <head>  …", status: 404, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "Not Found" }
does it mean that My MVC controller Action is not found ?

Comment: a `404` error means that the resource was not found on the server. Typically, you were not pointing to the good url

Answer (score 0):

It works with

```
$http.get("OPCVMLoad")
```

instead of

```
$http.get("GrilleFast/OPCVMLoad")
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow John ;-). I'm flagging this answer as "not an answer". To me, it looks more like a comment, and will never help someone in the future who would have an error like the one your title describes.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.